# C# How to set the default value of an object in the propertygrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an object which inherits from Button. This button is a property of an object which inherit from TableLayoutPanel. The property is called `MyButton`:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
**[DefaultValue(??? Something Like Visible = false ???)]**
public CustomButton MyButton
{
    get { return _button; }
    set { _button = value; }
}
```

Now, in the designer, I want to set the `Visible` property of `MyButton` to be false. Default the `Visible` property true, but in this case, I want it to be false.

How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK, you'll have to set that Attribute directly on the desired Property, which means at the `Visible`-property of the button.

Comment: But the `Visible` property is on the Button class, not in my own class. Can I overwrite this?

Comment: Then you'll have to encapsulate that button into your own class and override that property.

Comment: That doesn't work, because then VS 2010 crashes

Comment: That's a problem...you might want to file a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I can't do this because my property isn't of type bool. It is a CustomButton.

Comment: You can do it for all types, as long as the default value type matches the property's type.

Comment: That is exactly why it isn't going to work for me, because the property is of type `CustomButton`.

Comment: If you are attempting to change the actual property of CustomButton, the last line in the setter should set the properties that you want. _button.Visible = false;

Answer (score 1):

Because your value is not a constant value it cannot be used with `DefaultValueAttribute` since these values are required at compile time.  Instead you can disregard `DefaultValueAttribute` and in the constructor you can initialize the `MyButton` attribute with a custom instance of `CustomButton` with the default attributes set on it.  The only irregularity here is that in the property grid the property value will appear bold as if the user had changed it.

Here is an example:

```
public YourCustomControlClass()
{
    this.MyButton = new CustomButton { Visible = false; };
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of it? I don't understand it completely.

Answer (score 1):

in your `MyButton` Class, ***remove*** anything you've added trying to override the **Visible** property add following code:

```
public MyButton()
{
    this.Visible=false;
}
```

Rebuild it, then add a new Mybutton instance to your form, you can see its visible property in the Designer is set to False now.

Comment: I don't use the `MyButton` instances directly on my form. I have a customPanel where the buttons are on. Via the Custom panel I expose the buttons with properties. When I set the `Visible` property in the constructor to false, and in the designer I set the CustomPanel.MyButton.Visible property to true, the button stays invisible

Comment: I know you don't use **Mybutton** directly, but you must have access to **Mybutton.cs** (otherwise you should call it **Theirbutton** :)), modify it as I stated in my answer, rebuild it, and then you will get the result you want.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but it doesn't work. The property is indeed false, but when I set it to true, it doesn't show the button. But when I don't do `this.Visible = false` the button is visible. But I don't want that, by default the button must be invisble

Comment: Another thing when setting the Visible property in the constructor to false. When in the designer I set the property to true, I build the project (not run, just build) and than go back to the same property it is changed back to false. I can send you the project if you want?

Comment: I know your problem now: When you set `this.Visible = false` in the constructor, you'll only be able to change it back to `true` by using the code but not the designer.....

Comment: Exactly. That's the problem. And I'd like to know how to change the value by using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Override the property and then set the default value:

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
new public bool Visible
{
  get { return base.Visible; }
  set { base.Visible = value; }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't matter what value I set in the designer, the button is always invisible

Comment: @Martijn: Then you have something else wrong. If setting the property in the designer doesn't work, it's not going to work if you set it in code, whether with an attribute or not.

Comment: See the edited version, in which override the property and then set the default value.

Comment: Maybe it is my system, but when I do this, VS crashes when I open my form to design.

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't really crash, which version of VS it is?

Comment: It is pretty stable version, not much idea why it is crashing.